# Where to put "pwl_english.dict" file?

Tags: lyx, spellchecking

I have an old `pwl_english.dict` file (from an old LyX 2.2 installation). Where do I put it in my new LyX 2.3 folder so that spell check correctly recognizes the words in that file as correctly spelled?

I've tried both `C:\Program Files\LyX 2.3` and `C:\Program Files\LyX 2.3\Resources\dicts` but those don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\LyX2.3
```

Replace the `XXX` with the appropriate name on your system.

The above directory is the "User directory". You can find out what your user directory is by going to "About LyX", which on Windows and Linux is under the "Help" menu, and on macOS is under the "LyX" menu.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question and helping future visitors to this question. When you next see this, is there any chance you could accept your own answer with the tickmark so the `community` bot doesn't bump it every few months please?

Comment: In addition to JamesT's comment, perhaps you could generalize the answer. Can you look in Help > About and specify which location is correct? Is it indeed the library directory? That way, people on macOS or Linux can find the solution.

Comment: @scottkosty: "Help > About" shows "Library directory: C:\Program Files\LyX 2.3\Resources\" and "User directory: ~\AppData\Roaming\LyX2.3\". (I'm not sure what exactly you mean but if that helps could you just edit my above answer accordingly? Thanks.)

Comment: Thanks for that info! I made the edit.

Comment: @JamesT There is an even easier way how to stop the community bot from bumping posts yourself: vote for them (either up or down, as you seem fit, both will stop the bumping)